# Как можно расположить кнопку по центру картинки?

Tags: html, css

Есть задача: картинка - экран монитора, по центру хотелось бы расположить кнопку, например "Заказать услугу", как это можно сделать без media.css?

Answer (score 3):

Вариант 1

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    background: #ccc;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<button>Заказать услугу</button>
```

Вариант 2

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    background: #ccc;  
    position: relative;
}

button{
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<button>Заказать услугу</button>
```

Comment: вариант 1 по лучше

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так

```css
body {
margin:0;
}
.buy {
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
height:100vh;
}
.button {
padding:10px;
border:1px solid #095;
border-radius:5rem;
color:#095;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:sans-serif;
transition:1s all;
}
.button:hover {
background:#095;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="buy">
  <a class="button" href="javascript:void(0)">Заказать услугу</a>
</div>
```